# Scikit-learn KNN(K Nearest Neighbors ) parallelize using Apache Spark

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have been working on machine learning KNN (K Nearest Neighbors) algorithm with Python and Python's Scikit-learn machine learning API.

I have created sample code with toy dataset simply using python and Scikit-learn and my KNN is working fine. But As we know Scikit-learn API is build to work on single machine and hence once I will replace my toy data with millions of dataset it will decrease my output performance.

I have searched for many options, help and code examples, which will distribute my machine learning processing parallel using spark with Scikit-learn API, but I was not found any proper solution and examples.

Can you please let me know how can I achieve and increase my performance with Apache Spark and Scikit-learn API's K Nearest Neighbors?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Your question is very broad. However, I think this post might help you [Auto scaling sci-kit learn with Apache Spark](https://databricks.com/blog/2016/02/08/auto-scaling-scikit-learn-with-apache-spark.html)

Comment: Hi @AlbertoBonsanto, I have gone through the link you have given, but I don't find how to scale my Scikit-learn KNN with Spark. I have also gobe through third party package for Scikit-learn available on Spark's official web site but I'm not sure the about the API and not finding much help with proper example.

Answer (score 1):

Well according to discussions `https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-2336` here MLLib (Machine Learning Library for Apache Spark) does not have an implementation of KNN. 
You could try `https://github.com/saurfang/spark-knn`.

Comment: Hi Krishna, Yes Spark MLlib doesn't have support for KNN. But here I'm not using Spark's MLlib for machine learning. I'm using Python and Scikit-learn KNN. But the problem is with heavy dataset my algo taking hours to train the dataset and prediction. So I want to leverage Spark distribution power with my existing python KNN implementation which reduce my process time.

Comment: Here spark can only help for hyper parameter optimisation techniques like grid search. I am not sure if you can achieve what you are asking for.

Comment: Hi Krishna, you are right. But I was thinking dividing model processing into separate batches and parallelize all the batch processing using spark into cluster. I thought that way we can achieve parallelism but I have to try that with actual data and see dose it make any impact on processing time or not. Thanks .